# Manipulate data structures in protobuf using c++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I want to modify the data structure defined in protobuf, the proto is like this:

```
message DoubleMap {
   map<string, double> double_map = 1
}

message DoubleVector {
   map<string, DoubleMap> double_vector = 1
}

message Data {
   repeated DoubleVector data = 1
}
```

I need to new, modify and delete on Data, it's much easier if the data structure is defined in C++. My question is do I need to have a Loader that take a protobuf input and build a data structure in C++? Or build my own helper functions based on protobuf generated functions?

Comment: What's wrong with the C++ classes generated by `protoc` compiler from your .proto definition? What do they lack that you feel you need?

Comment: "do I need" how do you expect somebody would tell you what you need?

Comment: If given `Data d`, I want to access one double value in DoubleMap,like `d.data.double_vector.double_map["key"]`. Then if I just use the helper functions in the protoc generated code then it's super long.

Answer (score 0):

According the [protobuf doc](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial), google encourages you to write wrappers:

[image: Google encourages to write wrappers]